# Proving a statement using the definition of a limit

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta

Let $f$ be a function that is defined on a deleted neighbourhood of $x_0 ∈ \Bbb R$,
such that $f(x) \ne 0$ for every $x$ on that deleted neighbourhood. Suppose that
$$\lim _{x\to x_0} f(x) = \lim_{x\to x_0} (f(x) + 1/|f(x)|) = 0 $$

(a) Prove that there exists a $δ > 0$ such that for every $0 < |x − x_0| < δ$, we have $f(x) < 0$.

(b) Set $g(x) = f(x)+ 1/|f(x)|$
for every $0 < |x−x_0| < δ$. Find an expression
for $f(x)$ as a function of $g(x)$ for every $0 < |x − x_0| < δ$.

(c) Conclude that $\lim_{ x→x_0}f(x) = −1$.

I'm having trouble with proving a, we are given an hint to prove first that  for every $y > 0$,  $y +
1/y ≥ 2$,
and I did, but I've been trying to manipulate the inequation in the definition of the limit without success.
How should I approach this?

- EDIT -

Okay so I ended up proving the hint, manipulating it to look like this

if y>0 then y+1/|y|≥2 for every y in R

and then I used the contrapositive of this expression, which I found to be

if y+1/|y|<2 then 0≥y for every y in R.

and I used the contrapositive in the definition of the limit, chose epsilon = 2 and showed f(x)<0 in that deleted neighbourhood.

My question now is if my manipulation of the proof of the hint, and the contrapositive is legal..

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Are you sure of the initial hypothesis on $f$? The limit can't depend on $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)>0$ for all $\delta$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta$, you get $f(x)+\frac{1}{|f(x)|}=f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)}\geq2$, and that is a contradiction, because $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)}=0$. Then $f(x)<0$ for some $|x-x_0|<\delta$.

Comment: Can you explain how is this a contradiction? I'm quiet new to limits and I just can't see it.

Comment: Limit in a way means the expression can get arbitrarily close to 0, provided x is close enough to $x_0$, which cannot be the case if the expression is bounded below by 2.

Comment: Because for all $\varepsilon$ exists a $\delta$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)+1/f(x)|<\varepsilon$, then if you choose $\varepsilon=1$ there exist a $\delta$ such that $|f(x)+1/f(x)|<1$.